# How can I integrate sqlite3's fulltext search in a Pony ORM application

Tags: sqlite, orm, full-text-search, ponyorm

Python's standard library module sqlite3 support [loading sqlite extensions](http://file:///usr/share/doc/python-docs-3.4.3/html/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.enable_load_extension), also the fulltext search one. The ORM Peewee [also includes support](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#FTSModel). (Both support [FTS3/FTS4](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) and Peewee also [explicitly supports](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#FTS5Model) [FTS5](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html).

*How would I best integrate sqlite3's fulltext search, be it FTS3/FTS4 or FTS5, in a Pony ORM application?*

I suppose that in principle, I can connect to the database with the sqlite3 module or even Peewee and use their functionality. However, I do not know whether there are any gotcha's regarding concurrent access to the database file. Also perhaps it is possible to integrate the fulltext search better, so that, e.g., fulltext searches can be done using comprehension syntax.